# From multiple strings, efficiently build single buffer with spans to it

Tags: c++, compression

I'm trying to find a decent algorithm to efficiently create immutable string buffer.
I have an array of string values and I wish to convert them into a string_view that points to a single buffer.

I can do this by simply appending input string into single one, but I wish to be result string as small as possible by arranging input strings where there be as little duplicate substrings as possible.

Here is a practical example:

```
inputs:
  settings
  array
  node_data
  raycast
  dataset
  ray

output buffer:
  arraycastnode_datasettings

output_spans:
....................settings
..array.....................
...........node_data........
....raycast.................
................dataset.....
....ray.....................
```

For visualization, output_spans are indented to tell where they begin within the main buffer. By design output values must be exactly the same as inputs.

Here is a C++ example:

```cpp
std::vector<std::string> inputs{"settings","array","node_data","raycast","dataset","ray"};

std::vector<std::string_view> outputs;

// mainBuffer will be: arraycastnode_datasettings
std::string mainBuffer = CompressStrings(std::move(inputs), outputs);
```

Anyone knows the algorithm name or better, a library that implements this?
This seems like fairly simple compression and I am certain someone in 60s already wrote something about this.

Comment: According to <https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_common_supersequence#Shortest_common_superstring>, this is NP-hard. The approach that implements it as finding the lowest weight set cover would probably have some library that does the heavy lifting.

Comment: Thank you @Artyer Shortest Common Superstring is exactly I was looking for.
Please post it as an answer.